# Installing the Android USB driver - not happening

Tags: android, interface, usb, adb

Using AVD, I successfully obtained the USB driver.  I followed the instructions on this page [USB Driver for Windows](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) but Windows never prompted with the "Found new hardware..." message.

I'm running Vista x64 SP2 and I can see the amd64 folder under ~\Android SDK\tools\usb_driver.

The Manage Devices applet shows no listing for "ADB Interface" so it certainly appears that it is not there.  I tried a scan for hardware changes -- nada.  And running "adb devices" comes back empty (as expected).

How do I install the ADB Interface?

Comment: Please expand the link - too hard to ascertain where to go.  And, to ask a stupid question, do you have something plugged into the USB cable? (Asked only because you don't explicitly state that you have done so)

Comment: I updated the original link and it is here http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html.

Yes, I do have the device connected via USB.

Answer (score 2):

Enable "usb debugging" in your phone (settings - applications - development).

Answer (score 1):

I got my HTC Magic to install on Win-7 using Android SDK drivers, although process was not straightforward.

Right click on the Android phone item, then left-click on Update Driver Software.
Choose "Browse my computer for software"

Next, DO NOT click Browse... button to select the \google\usb_driver, if you do that you will get a message about Win 7 not being able to install the driver.

Instead, click on "Let me pick from a list"

Then a box appears with types of device, I chose All Devices and then click Next.

Then you get a list of device drivers, and at the bottom is a button "Have Disk..."
Click that button and navigate to the \google\usb_driver folder and select it, I then got a list of three items, one of which was the Android ADB Interface.

Click Next to install and for me that worked.

No idea why it doesn't work from the first Browse... button. But the longer way round did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to a Linux machine, It would be a lot easier to do it on that.
But assuming you don't...

Can you find the device in the device manager? if so you could install the driver that way, see "Windows Vista: Upgrade an existing driver" [here](http://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)

Also, do you even see it as a mass storage device?

Comment: As mentioned, "ADB Interface" (the expected name of the device in Dev Manager) doesn't appear.  I only see the device under storage.  Nothing appears under USB.

Odd thing is Eclipse and Android SDK have installed fine, I can download and install plug-ins via AVD Manager, the emulator works and runs code.  But this is the first time I've attempted to install something on my device.

Answer (score 0):

I derived the solution after reading this page [How-To #0: How to Install Usb Driver on Your Computer](http://android-simplicity.blogspot.com/2009/08/how-to-1-how-to-install-usb-driver-on.html?showComment=1267321225161_AIe9_BGlg_u1WXL7adlUuPAjR8W6bMvPa4xTNFj6WfOwKUiYqUwMbBMK9AgQh6MdcjdBU6Y1J1RBTa1HuLhhS6QGKKR5y0fb26Tzi2mKFmEzCrMXviJIsOwsZ1tJ5LHBLIdANOFgdo3KMwShqnikoN-8bKWfQ_sS1GkuZaJ5VUtswyJn5L5d9DN1xfmBsoukK52YLobjUw1mzk1C_mjynn1xSJtDehW4w1ykJRXBBivMqqSKGiPxvbtQbnvjPj7fpi-LQGEHpiWc#c1250768003786005624).  Though the listed instructions didn't work for me, it did lead me to the solution so: credit where credit is due.

Vista automatically recognized the SD card and will install a USB Mass Storage Driver for that.  Contrary to the instructions on the linked page, I **did not** have to remove this driver.  Another comment in the text led me to needing to enable debugging mode (Settings -> Applications -> Development -> Debugging Mode).  As soon as I enabled this (with the device connected), Vista immediately installed an "Unknown" driver for the connection and I was able to successfully update the driver.  Works great!