# Windows refuses to install Android ADB driver

Tags: android, usb, windows-7-x64

I am trying to connect debugger to an Android phone (HTC myTouch 4G Android 2.3) from a Windows 7 64-bit pc.

Interestingly enough, everything worked fine for a few months until about a week ago Windows just started using a default Android driver instead of the HTC driver with ADB support.

I tried instructions from here:  [Installing the Android USB driver - not happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2346119/installing-the-android-usb-driver-not-happening)

but it does not work.  I tried restarting, re-installing drivers, restoring to an earlier point, nothing helps.

Under "Devices and Printers" my phone appears as a generic "Android Phone".  When I try to update the driver and browse to C:\Program Files (x86)\HTC\HTC Driver\Driver Files\Win7_x64 where HTC driver is installed I get the following message:

"Windows has determined the driver software for your device is up to date".
WPD FileSystem Volume Driver.

USB debugging is obviously enabled on the phone.  The next step is to re-install Windows, but I want to avoid it and plus there is no guarantee that it will even work.

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

## Windows is a monolithic mess

Try a few of these, if you're lucky a magic pixie will come and nudge your driver thus fixing it.

### 1. Uninstall Reinstall

***Uninstall*** the generic driver from device manager probably.
***Reinstall*** HTC drivers

### 2. Uninstall clean reinstall

***Uninstall*** the generic driver from device manager probably.
***Clean*** the registry and other stuff using CCleaner (I trust this app)
***Reinstall*** HTC drivers

---

### Longshot

***Upgrade to Win8 and do a refresh system.***

Answer (score 1):

Download and install HTC Sync Manager from HTC:

http://www.htc.com/www/support/software/htc-sync-manager.aspx

This will install the needed drivers on your computer. Let us know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

It just started working for no apparent reason.

Thank you so much for your suggestions, but I really don't know what (if anything) out of the things I tried worked.